Devops issue with pushing image to Artifactory
Getting the following error when pushing the image to Artifactory

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.1.1:build (default-cli) on project backend: Unknown mediaType: application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json.

Getting the below error when am trying to push the image dockerized by jib using the maven plugin to my organisation's internal Artifactory. What could be the possible cause?
trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - jfrogtest
    
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'  # You can use other images if needed
    
    variables:
      - group: artifactory
      - name: dockerRegistryServiceConnection
        value: 'Artifactory-docker'
      - name: containerRegistry
        value: 'danfoss-docker.jfrog.io'
      - name: imageRepository
        value: 'plus1connect-backend-service-ui'
      - group: New-Portal-Backend
      - name: imagePullSecret
        value: 'artifactory'
    
    steps:
    - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '11'
        jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
        jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
    
    
     - script: |
        mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip
      displayName: 'Maven Build'
    
     - script: |
        mvn -X compile jib:build -Dmaven.test.skip -Djib.to.auth.username=$(artifactory.user) -Djib.to.auth.password=$(artifactory.password) -Djib.to.image=$(docker-server-image-name):$(image-tag) -Djib.container.format=Docker
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/backend'
    
    
     - task: KubernetesManifest@0
      displayName: Create imagePullSecret
      inputs:
        action: createSecret
        secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
        dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        kubernetesServiceConnection: dev.plus1connect.aks
        
      
     - task: KubernetesManifest@0
      inputs:
        action: deploy
        kubernetesServiceConnection: 'dev.plus1connect.aks'
        namespace: 'default'
        manifests: |
          $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/.manifests/*.yml

The Maven repository is created in JFrog Artifactory.

did you setup your target repository for maven artifacts? You should have a repository for docker images as target.

How do you set the OCI Image Manifest for your Docker image? Provide the detailed content of the Manifest?


Please share your completed YAML file of your pipeline. 2. What's the result if you run the same scripts shared above on your local machine? If it fails locally, you need to investigate your project further. Share the configuration of your project. 3. You can try to use the extension JFrog Artifactory published by JFrog to publish your image.


@ZiyangLiu-MSFT - added the yaml file used to push image to jfrog,
artifactory credentials are stored in library. changes are made in pom.xml accordingly.

Hi @shuchi srivastava, I have shared an example of building and pushing image to JFrog for your reference. Please check if it works for you.

Hi @shuchi srivastava. it's great to know my answer works for you. To help others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept my answer below according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!

Here is my example of building and pushing image to JFrog Artifactory for your reference.

Set up pom.xml to use the Jib plugin.

    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <to>
                        <image>${docker.image.prefix}/imagename:imagetag</image>
                        <auth>
                            <username>${env.ARTIFACTORY_USER}</username>
                            <password>${env.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}</password>
                        </auth>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>



Set Up Environment Variables in the Azure pipeline and trigger a build.

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  ARTIFACTORY_USER: $(artifactory.user)
  ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD: $(artifactory.password)
  DOCKER_IMAGE_PREFIX: ***.jfrog.io/{repository name}

steps:
- script: |
    mvn -X compile jib:build  -Djib.to.image=$(DOCKER_IMAGE_PREFIX)/my-test-image:11-ubuntu -Djib.to.auth.username=$(ARTIFACTORY_USER) -Djib.to.auth.password=$(ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD) -Djib.container.format=Docker
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/complete'


Result: The image is successfully build and published to JFrog Artifactory.
In the Azure Pipeline Log:

In the JFrog Artifactory:



